# Using dynamic variable names in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to use dynamic variable names. So inside this loop I want to create `$file0`, `$file1`, and `$file2`:

```
for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $("file" . $i) = file($filelist[$i]);
}

var_dump($file0);
```

The return is `null` which tells me it's not working. I have no idea what the syntax or the technique I'm looking for is here, which makes it hard to research. `$filelist` is defined earlier on.

Comment: **Don't**! There is never a good reason to use them. They are, effectively, just an untidy array. Use a proper array instead.

Comment: Alright I'm sorry, I just went back and picked an answer for each question I've asked so far. Good thing it's only 7 :P

Comment: And Quentin, why are they bad practice?? There must be a reason they exist alongside arrays I'd think

Comment: @user1159454 — They are a disorganised mess without all the tools that can be applied to arrays available to them. They exist for ancient legacy reasons and crazy edge cases.

Comment: Crazy edge cases may be exactly why someone would want to ask this question.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/php-dynamic-variables.html

Comment: Debugging, understanding and bug fixing of such code can become a nightmare.

Comment: Careful if you are using it on $_POST or $_GET to put the parameters into variables through a loop. Someone could maliciously (or accidentally) overwrite existing variables.

Comment: Thanks folks. I searched for the question as I was thinking that ${} was the right way to go for an array of values I'm building from a database. But your comments made me reevaluate my "design" choices and I'm simply updating a multidimensional associative array with the results from the database query (it's a long list of attributes) rather that storing each result in a separate dynamically created variable.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

Wrap them in `{}`:

```
${"file" . $i} = file($filelist[$i]);
```

#### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/dYr0IxMI)

---

Using `${}` is a way to create dynamic variables, simple example:

```
${'a' . 'b'} = 'hello there';
echo $ab; // hello there
```

Comment: Is it also possible to create dynamic arrays with the same logic?

Comment: I have the same doubt of @dtakis, can you help us? If possible, please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591687/php-method-to-get-values-dynamically-from-an-array-object-property).

Comment: Jut a warning if you are using this to include a variable (the most useful way IMHO) don't forget to use double quotes. `${'fixedTime$i'} = $row['timeInstance'];` gives you a not very useful `$fixedTime$i` instead of `$fixedTime1, $fixedTime2` etc. (Fortunately spotted it almost straight away.)

Answer (score 115):

## Overview

In PHP, you can just put an extra `$` in front of a variable to make it a dynamic variable :

```
$$variableName = $value;
```

While I wouldn't recommend it, you could even chain this behavior :

```
$$$$$$$$DoNotTryThisAtHomeKids = $value;
```

You can but are not forced to put `$variableName` between `{}` :

```
${$variableName} = $value;
```

Using `{}` is only mandatory when the name of your variable is itself a composition of multiple values, like this :

```
${$variableNamePart1 . $variableNamePart2} = $value;
```

It is nevertheless recommended to always use `{}`, because it's more readable.

## Differences between PHP5 and PHP7

Another reason to always use `{}`, is that PHP5 and PHP7 have a slightly different way of dealing with dynamic variables, which results in a different outcome in some cases.

In PHP7, dynamic variables, properties, and methods will now be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order, as opposed to the mix of special cases in PHP5. The examples below show how the order of evaluation has changed.

#### Case 1 : `$$foo['bar']['baz']`

- PHP5 interpetation : `${$foo['bar']['baz']}`
- PHP7 interpetation : `${$foo}['bar']['baz']`

#### Case 2 : `$foo->$bar['baz']`

- PHP5 interpetation : `$foo->{$bar['baz']}`
- PHP7 interpetation : `$foo->{$bar}['baz']`

#### Case 3 : `$foo->$bar['baz']()`

- PHP5 interpetation : `$foo->{$bar['baz']}()`
- PHP7 interpetation : `$foo->{$bar}['baz']()`

#### Case 4 : `Foo::$bar['baz']()`

- PHP5 interpetation : `Foo::{$bar['baz']}()`
- PHP7 interpetation : `Foo::{$bar}['baz']()`

Comment: A good answer to a dubious topic. I'm really glad i don't have to debug such code.

Comment: best answer since it just answers the question without being judgemental

Comment: Yeah, we just had some trouble with some legacy code aswell. Production was PHP5.5, Dev environment was PHP7. I am favouriting this question.

Answer (score 22):

Try using `{}` instead of `()`:

```
${"file".$i} = file($filelist[$i]);
```

Comment: from phpNET manual http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php

`$price_for_monday = 10;
$price_for_tuesday = 20;
$today = 'tuesday';

$price_for_today = ${ 'price_for_' . $today};
echo $price_for_today; // will return 20
`

Answer (score 8):

I do this quite often on results returned from a query..

e.g.

```
// $MyQueryResult is an array of results from a query

foreach ($MyQueryResult as $key=>$value)
{
   ${$key}=$value;
}
```

Now I can just use $MyFieldname (which is easier in echo statements etc) rather than $MyQueryResult['MyFieldname']

Yep, it's probably lazy, but I've never had any problems.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use extract() function of PHP?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: handy one-liner for DB result sets: foreach($row as $k=>$v){$$k=$v}

Answer (score 3):

Tom if you have existing array you can convert that array to object and use it like this:

```
$r = (object) $MyQueryResult;
echo $r->key;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using {} instead of ():

```
${"file".$i} = file($filelist[$i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

i have a solution for dynamically created variable value and combined all value in a variable.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $r=0;
    for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){
        $a = $_POST['a'.$i];
        $r .= $a;
    }
    echo $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a position where I had 6 identical arrays and I needed to pick the right one depending on another variable and then assign values to it.  In the case shown here $comp_cat was 'a' so I needed to pick my 'a' array ( I also of course had 'b' to 'f' arrays)

Note that the values for the position of the variable in the array go after the closing brace.

> ${'comp_cat_'.$comp_cat.'_arr'}[1][0] = "FRED BLOGGS";
>
> ${'comp_cat_'.$comp_cat.'_arr'}[1][1] = $file_tidy;
>
> echo 'First array value is '.$comp_cat_a_arr[1][0].' and the second value is .$comp_cat_a_arr[1][1];

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the mentioned above, it worked the simple way:
It's accessed as $_POST variable, as it comes directly out of a dynamic form.

```
$variableName= "field_".$id;
echo $_POST[$variableName];
```