# Can I declare a variable name like this $(variable name) in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, variable-declaration

I want to get the resulting string(field name) of the mysql function, mysql_field_name() and declare that as a variable,so that I can use it later in my program.
For example, like this:

```
$(mysql_field_name($result,2)) = 2;
```

Here, can I use this statement like this : `$(mysql_field_name($result,2));`
Is it a correct variable declaration?
Will it work and will it declare a variable with field name as the variable name?

Comment: why dont you try that out ?

Comment: docs: [Variable variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-php

Answer (score 4):

```
${mysql_field_name($result,2)} = 2
```

http://codepad.org/NRok2Cha

Comment: this one seems more elegant to me :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do what you want in PHP:

```
$varname = mysql_field_name($result, 2);
$$varname = 2;
```

More info in the PHP manual: [Variable variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)