# What does {} mean?

Tags: php

I found this in code, what does it mean and whats the difference between that and normal $dir variable?

```
global ${$dir};

$this->{$dir} = new $class();
```

Comment: This is dynamic name. More http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-php

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Its called complex curly syntax.

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognized when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to
>   get a literal {$.

More info:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 13):

It is taking the value of the `$dir` variable and finding the variable with that name.

So if `$dir = 'foo';`, then `${$dir}` is the same as `$foo`.

Likewise, if `$dir = 'foo';`, then `$this->{$dir}` is the same as `$this->foo`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

They are used to wrap the name of variable variables.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamically created variable. For example:

```
$app = new App();
$app->someMethod('MyDB');

// global
$config = array('user' => 'mark', 'pass' => '*****');

class App {

    // MyDB instance
    protected $config;

    public function someMethod($class) {

        $dir = 'config';

        // $config = array('user' => 'mark', 'pass' => '*****')
        global ${$dir};
        // not static variable !!!
        $this->{$dir} = new $class();
    }
}

class MyDB {
  // body
}
```