# PHP Dynamic Variable Name

Tags: php

I want a dynamic property name like this:

```
$_taxVocabName = 'name';
$node->field_ . $_taxVocabName;
```

This should call:

```
$node->field_name
```

How can I do this?

I could not find anything on php.net or elsewhere.

Thanks Sascha

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php this is what you want I think

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-php - this should help

Comment: `$node->{'field_' . $_taxVocabName}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways:

First, use a variable:

```
$property = 'field_' . $_taxVocabName;

$node->$property;
```

Second, use curly brackets:

```
$node->{'field_' . $_taxVocabName};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd think a much better way to do this would be

```
$taxVocabName = "name";
$property = "field_" . $taxVocabName;
```

Then you would have to set the variable to a value of course...

like so:

```
$$property = "My variable variable";
```

or:

```
$field_name = "My variable variable";
```

I know it's a bit later, but maybe this will help someone else down the road.