# display database variables in file

Tags: php, mysqli

So I had my variables all hard coded into my page like so:

```
$base_url = 'something'; 
$logo_url = 'somethingelse';
```

And then I went and put all these into a database for easier updating, Now I need to place them back into the config.php file so my website can use them.

I tried doing the following: (database.php includes all the connection details)

```
function get_identifiers() {
  require_once 'database.php';
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM settings");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $identifier = $row['identifier'];
    $value = $row['value'];
            $identifier = $value
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
}
```

But I got nothing. What can I do?

Comment: Turn on some `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, it will tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you making $identifier = $value. Also this is missing a ; at the end of the line

Comment: Pull the require statement out of the function, put it at the top of your php file, just for good practice.

Comment: @Dan: It's a `require_once`, so it shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Blank page. That's what I got. I added: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: What do you mean by "I got nothing"?  What are you doing with `$identifier` and `$value`?  Also, why are you overwriting those variables for each row?

Comment: I had it hard coded in my file to begin with. Now I need to repopulate that list using a database query. `$base_url = 'something';` and then in my regular pages I am `echo $base_url;` to echo out the url `something`

Comment: I think that you are looking for [dynamic variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php) - `${$identifier} = $value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your identifiers in an array, return it, and then extract it:

```
require_once 'database.php';

function get_identifiers() {
  $retval = array();

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM settings");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $identifier = $row['identifier'];
    $value = $row['value'];
    $retval[$identifier] = $value;
  }
  mysqli_close($con);

  return $retval;
}
```

Then run this on your page:

```
extract(get_identifiers());
```

This will change all of your settings into variables, as you want.

Comment: Or, you know, have `get_identifiers` return a value.

Comment: Then would I have to change what I put in my regular pages to echo out the value? Right now I have: `echo $base_url;`

Comment: He's pulling **settings** from his database. Usually, settings are _system-wide_. However, based on his last comment I'll provide another solution.

Comment: Try it now. This will put all of your identifiers into an array, return then array, and then extract the keys in your array, turning them into variables.

Comment: Yay! Was it a misspelling? You should consider registering for Stack Overflow so that you have a unique name and can keep building your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because your making $identifier = $value...  If you want to get the name of the identifier as the variable name use $$identifier = $value;

however I too would suggest using either object or array

```
$config = new stdClass;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $indentifier = $row['identifier'];
    $config->$identifier = $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: The OP's big point though was that he needs to use `echo $base_url;`, and does not want to change his code. Still, I love assigning dynamic variables to a stdClass, +1.