# declaring a big list of variables

Tags: php, variables, declare

I have a big list of variables:

```
$variable_1 = $_POST['variable_1'];
$variable_2 = $_POST['variable_2'];
$variable_3 = $_POST['variable_3'];
$variable_4 = $_POST['variable_4'];
...
..
.
$variable_86 = $_POST['variable_86'];
```

What would be the best way to declare all of these variables? Should I just declare them all like above, should I put them in an array, can I declare using a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 86; $i++){
     if (isset($_POST["variable_$i"]))
     ${'variable'.$i} = $_POST["variable_$i"];
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php) question to learn about Dynamic Variable names.

EDIT: Added the [isset](http://www.php.net/isset) command. `isset()` checks whether a variable is already declared or not

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work but it gives me a `Notice: Undefined index: ` error

Comment: Use `isset()` to check if the variable is defined or not.

Comment: Another Happy Ending :)

Comment: That loop is pretty much equal to `extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);`

Comment: Only thing is it doesn't affect the other `$_POST` variables while `extract()` does :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following:

```
foreach($var as $key=>$value) {
echo $value;
}
```

and/or:

```
foreach($_POST['var'] as $key=>$value) {
echo $value;
```

You could use this also, that will iterate through all `POST` values:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
echo "$key=$value";
}
```

Also, assuming `$_POST['variable_1']` `$_POST['variable_2']` etc.

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k, 'variable_') === 0) {
        echo "$k = $v";
    }
}
```