# Loop thru multiple integers

Tags: php, for-loop

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++)
    if(!empty($room_ID.($i+1)) 
     && !empty($date_from.($i+1)) 
     && !empty($date_to.($i+1)) )
```

I have 8x3 integers.. Id like to know if there is a way to loop thru all of them with a for loop like giving $i to the end of the integer names like so:

```
room_ID1
room_ID2
date_from1
date_from2
etc..
```

Best answer would be in php, but i could use anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the variable variables in braces. Try this:

```
<?php
$room_ID1 = 123;
$date_from1 = "2014-01-01";
$date_to1 = "2014-01-30";

for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++)
    if(!empty(${'room_ID'.($i+1)}) 
     && !empty(${'date_from'.($i+1)}) 
     && !empty(${'date_to'.($i+1)}) )
{
    echo ${'room_ID'.($i+1)};
}
```

More info:
http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to interpolate the variable names at runtime.  You can accomplish this like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++)
    if(!empty(${'room_ID'.($i+1)}) 
         && !empty(${'date_from'.($i+1)}) 
         && !empty(${'date_to'.($i+1))} )
```

In general, the recipe is: `${'base_name' . (derived computation)}`

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Comment: Not sure if i get it why to put the variables between '', your first answer worked too, like this:
${room_ID.($i+1)}

Comment: by default, bare strings that are not defined constants are converted to strings (yet will also issue a warning).  It is not recommended to rely on this behavior. e.g. `test` will be interpreted as a string (`'test'`) if the constant `test` has not been defined