# How to loop for php available like this?

Tags: php, loops

How to loop for php available name like this ?

```
<?PHP
for ($i=1;$i>10:$i++)
    {
        $group_$i_temp = ($i+$i);
    }
echo $group_5_temp;
?>
```

It's will `echo` 10

how to do that ?

Comment: Can you be more clear on your requirement?

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php

Comment: I think your loop condition is wrong. It should be for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) to make it meaningful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
    $name = "group_{$i}_temp";
    $$name = ($i+$i);
}
echo $group_5_temp;
```

Comment: I think this is expected answer OP wants. **+1**