# Looping through array and creating a new array with the name of the parameter matched

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array, whereby, if a condition is matched, all elements of that array should be stored into a new array named after the condition it matched.

```
     $unique_states = array_unique($allstates);
       $total = count($states);
       for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
        foreach($unique_states as $keys =>  $values){
             if(($states[$i][3] == $values)){
          $values[] = $states[$i];
        }
        }
    }
```

`$states` is the mega array that contains everything. When I loop through the array so that if this condition `if(($states[$i][3] == $values))` is matched, a new array should be created with the name of `$values`.

When I run the code and `print_r($values)`, I get `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`. When I change the name to something totally different, I simply get all the array in `$states`.

Not sure how to do this anymore.

Edit:

When I remove the `foreach` loop and insert the actual values of `$values` like this

```
  if(($states[$i][3] == 'state1')){
          $states1[] = $states[$i];
        }

  if(($states[$i][3] == 'state2')){
          $states2[] = $states[$i];
        }
```

it works very well. But in a case where I have several states, the code above will not be efficient enough and will require that I make changes each time a new state is added.
I need to return an array of the whole elements..i.e $states[$i] for which $states[$i][3] matched.

[image]

Example of data from $states input:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => firstname1
        [1] => lastname1
        [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
        [3] => state1
        [4] => email1
        [5] => address1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => firstname2
        [1] => lastname2
        [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
        [3] => state1
        [4] => email2
        [5] => address2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => firstname3
        [1] => lastname3
        [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
        [3] => state1
        [4] => email3
        [5] => address3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => firstname4
        [1] => lastname4
        [2] => Cannon Heathcare Center
        [3] => state2
        [4] => email4
        [5] => address4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => firstname5
        [1] => lastname5
        [2] => Cannon Heathcare Center
        [3] => state2
        [4] => email5
        [5] => address5
    )
```

Example out put should look something like this

```
Array
(
[state1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname1
                [1] => lastname1
                [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
                [3] => state1
                [4] => email1
                [5] => address1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname2
                [1] => lastname2
                [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
                [3] => state1
                [4] => email2
                [5] => address2
            )

Array
(
[state2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname1
                [1] => lastname1
                [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
                [3] => state2
                [4] => email1
                [5] => address1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => firstname2
                [1] => lastname2
                [2] => Armstrong Landscaping
                [3] => state2
                [4] => email2
                [5] => address2
            )
```

Comment: if $values equalls, for example, to 'thevalue' then what you are doing is: thevalue[] = $states[$i], which is wrong. So you need to add '$' at the beginning or in other words $$values[] = $states[$i]

Comment: @Andrew The same error still persists. `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: if you are using dynamic names for arrays, add brackets arround the dynamic-name: ${$values}[] = ... If you work with single variables only, no need for brackets

Comment: you have a multidimensional array, are you sure that $keys and $values are from correct level of $unique_states array?

Comment: what are the contents of $unique_states array? just before first (for) loop, print_r it's data

Comment: Before the for loop

Array
(
    [0] => state1
    [20] => state2
)

Comment: and you already updated code to use:  ${$values}[] = $states[$i]; ? If so, it must work. There is something wrong elsewhere..

Comment: Yes I have. What is get back is just the whole array.. same thing as $states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. When each condition is matched, it is stored inside a new multidimensional array.

```
$unique_states = array_unique($allstates);
      $total = count($states);
      for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
          foreach($unique_states as $keys =>  $values){
            if($states[$i][3] ==$values){
               $new[$values][$i] = $states[$i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
${$values} = array();
${$values}[] = $states[$i];
```

for output use: `print_r(${$values});`

For details read: [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Comment: When I insert ` ${$values} = array();` inside the `if()` loop, I only get the last element in `$states`..(the mega array). When I  insert outside the loops, I get undefined variables.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong with the structure of your whole mega loop. Try splitting into smaller parts and go step by step

Answer (score 1):

This can be done efficient with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
//ussing inline function requires PHP 5.3
$values = array_filter($states, function($state) {
   return (in_array($state[3], $unique_states));
});
```