# Can you have variables with spaces in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, space, names

I was messing around with variable variables in PHP, so I came up with the code:

```
$a = 'two words';  
$$a = 'something';  
echo $$a;  // outputs something
echo "$two words"; // error since $two doesn't exist
```

I was just trying to understand how PHP will behave if we have a string with spaces, and try to make a variable variable from it. And it seems it still stores the variable with spaces, since I did `var_dump($GLOBALS);` and I have this:

```
'a' => string 'two words' (length=9)  
'two words' => string 'something' (length=9)
```

I can access the 'two words' variable through `$GLOBALS['two words']` where two questions arise:

1. Can I somehow access it directly with the `$`? I've read somewhere that you need to get the whole variable in curly brackets (`{$two words}` or I assume `${two words}`), but that didn't work.
2. Can you actually have variables with spaces in PHP? I tried making an associative array with keys that contain spaces and that worked:

   ```
   $a['a space'] = 1;
   echo $a['a space']; // 1
   ```

Comment: Note the whitespace in $two words

Comment: `echo ${'two words'};`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9257505/3933332

Comment: @Ja͢ck + Rizier123 thank you very much!

Comment: Also check the [strings manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Comment: You can even declare a variable: `${"i-am a_variable<too>()!"} = "Hello bad variable!";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo "$two words"; // error since $two doesn't exist
```

The issue with this is that the string interpolation rules will stop at the first character that's not valid in a variable name. It is not specific to variable variables as such, it's specific to string interpolation.

This'll do:

```
echo ${'two words'};
```

But since this is rather awkward and doesn't work in all the same situations as valid variable names do (e.g. string interpolation), you really shouldn't do this ever.