# Get a PHP var with other PHP var

Tags: php, var

I know the title is not describing the problem very well, so I explain here:
I have multiple $_POST with similar names, like question1,question2,question3...

I have a for loop with $i. i want to get this vars ($question1, $question2), in help with $i. For example:

```
$question.$i = $_POST['question' . $i];
```

I want to do it because the number of questions is variable, so I have a button that add questions and answers to the page and then you submit it.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make explicitly `$question` an array.
Then you build your $_POST index by concatenating the string and `$i` with a `.`.

So, before the loop:

```
$question = array();
```

and in the loop:

```
$question[$i] = $_POST['question'.$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an array in your loop, this should fit:

```
${'question' . $i} = $_POST['question'.$i];
```

When `$i=1`, this will get you a `$question1` variable filled with then content of `$_POST['question1']`.

See also [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505) which adds insight on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $question = array();   
 $question[] = $_POST['question'.$i];
```

Use array to get your values.