# PHP dynamic variables

Tags: php

I have 30 variables to show, but write the code 30 times is not smart. how can I improve this code? Thank you!!

```
<?php if ($dimension_01_label) { ?> 
  <tr>
     <td><?= $dimension_01_label ?></td>
     <td><?= $dimension_01 ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }; ?>
<?php if ($dimension_02_label) { ?> 
  <tr>
    <td><?= $dimension_02_label ?></td>
    <td><?= $dimension_02 ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }; ?>
<?php if ($dimension_03_label) { ?> 
  <tr>
    <td><?= $dimension_03_label ?></td>
    <td><?= $dimension_03 ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Make an array and loop over it

Comment: Yeah, instead of 30 variables, have one array like `$dimension['$label'] = $value` or`$dimension[0] = array($label, $value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you redid your variable structure and used arrays, but using your current format you could do something like-

```
<?php
 for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++){
     if (${"dimension_".str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."_label"}) { ?> 
  <tr>
     <td><?= ${"dimension_".str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."_label"} ?></td>
     <td><?= ${"dimension_".str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)} ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php 
     }
  } 
?>
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use two things:

1. Use arrays and iterate throug it
2. Use dynamic variables via `{}` Examples here: [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `variable of variable` -

```
for($i = 1; $i <=30; $i++) {
    $var1 = "dimension_".str_pad($i, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)."_label";
    $var2 = "dimension_".str_pad($i, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if ($$var1) {
       echo "<td>".$$var1."</td><td>".$$var2."</td>";
    }
}
```

[Chekc Demo](https://eval.in/352958)

Comment: This code works fine, but is better when you puts <tr> before the first <td> and, </tr> after the last </td> to build lines in the table! However, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i++; $i<=30){
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php print $dimension_.$i."_label"; ?></td>
     <td><?php print $dimension_.$i; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this does not account for OPs `0` in `01`, `02`, etc.

Comment: you can use 'str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)' for that

Comment: first, in this case is necessary change the "for" putting $i++ after $i<30, however, in my case, using wordpress, this looping not print results...

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
$dimension[0] = something;
$dimension[1] = something;
```

and so on ...

and at time of printing them

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dimension);$i++)
{ ?>
<tr>
 <td><?= $dimension[$i] ?></td>
 <td><?= $dimension[$i] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}

?>
```