# How to Create Global Variable Dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.6

I need to create some global variable in PHP through function dynamically to be used out of function

I tried

```
<?php
function setthis(newglobal){
  global $_.newglobal._1;
  $_.newglobal._1 = "pampam";
}
setthis();

 echo $_newglobal_1;
?>
```

and I am getting this error

Line : 2,   Error type : 4

> Message : syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE)

I also tried wrap them in quoted the variable like

```
<?php
function setthis(newglobal){
  global $_.'newglobal'._1;
  $_newglobal_1 = "pampam";
}
setthis();

 echo $_newglobal_1;
?>
```

an I am getting error Message

> : syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE)

can you please let me know if this is doable in PHP? or what I am doing wrong?

> Update

```
<?php
function setthis($name){
    $GLOBALS[$name];
    $name = "pampam";
}
setthis();
echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is always in the function header:

```
function setthis(newglobal){
               //^^^^^^^^^ needs a '$' in front of it
```

Then simply use the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array, e.g.

```
function setthis($name, $value = "pampam"){
    $GLOBALS[$name] = $value;
}
```

Comment: why _always_ in the function header?

Comment: @Kenney Because in both attempts OP forgot the dollar sign to indicate a variable, so that's why he got the error in both code examples.

Comment: I don't follow. `$_.newglobal._1` also looks like it should not compile.

Comment: Thanks but I am still getting error on sample. Can you please take a look at update?

Comment: I do not pass the value on the function header since I need to calculate it from a database query

Comment: @Suffii The just write it in the function: `function setthis(){
    $GLOBALS["_newglobal_1"] = "pampam";
}`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09aa68e62d26475be5914f4fb6625f0513d52718

Comment: @Kenney Yes if OP wants to solve it by using the `global` keyword, he would have to do: `global $_newglobal_1; $_newglobal_1 = "pampam";`

Comment: I don't see a proper argument or local variable declaration in OP's code, maybe that can be covered too.. there are multiple errors, and the 'always' just seems out of place. The error is usually where the parser finds it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set dynamic variable names by using brackets:

```
$name = 'key';
${$name} = 'value';
echo $key; // Will echo 'value'
```

As described here:
[Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Your code would look something like:

```
<?php

function setthis($global_key, $global_value){
  global ${"_" . $global_key . "_1"};

  ${"_" . $global_key . "_1"} = $global_value;
}

setthis('newglobal', 'pampam value');

echo $_newglobal_1; // Will echo 'pampam value'

?>
```

Or you may use PHP's GLOBALS array, which is available (globally):

```
<?php

function setthis($global_key, $global_value){
  $GLOBALS[ $global_key ] = $global_value;
}

setthis('newglobal', 'pampam value');

echo $GLOBALS['newglobal']; // Will echo 'pampam value'

?>
```

Info on all of these are in the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php