# How to return the object value within for loop?

Tags: php, api

Okay so i am trying to retrieve the object value iterating through a for loop.

Manually it looks like this:

```
echo $game->stats->item0;
echo $game->stats->item1;
...
```

I want to do it something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo $game->stats->item.$i;
}
```

The above however just returns the value of $i. How can i return the actual object value?

Thanks

Comment: You need a Variable variable. So it would be `echo $game->stats->{"item$i"};`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php or http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your statement should be like this:

```
echo $game->stats->{'item'.$i}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `item.$i`, use `{"item$i"}`.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo $game->stats->{"item$i"};
}
```

Another way you can do it is to set a variable to be equal to `'item' . $i`.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $item = 'item' . $i;
    echo $game->stats->$item;
}
```