# how to add multiple values in array of session in php by dynamic generation of key

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to store **slug** values of multiple items in a **session array**

here is my **ajax script** through which I am posting slug name to the session:

```
 <script>
$('a.add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
    var slug = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/includes/session.php",
        data:{ prod_slug: slug }, 
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

here is my code of **session.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
 $slug = $_POST['prod_slug'];

 $arr = array('slug'=> $slug);
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION,$arr);
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

But as associative array should have unique key so it is overwriting values:

**$arr = array('slug'=> $slug);**

the key should have increment to store multiple values like:

$arr = array('**slug**'=> $slug);

$arr = array('**slug1**'=> $slug);

$arr = array('**slug2**'=> $slug);

How do I get this done.

Comment: I think this thread answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php

Comment: It would probably be easier to add an additional layer: `$_SESSION['slugs'][] = $slug`

Comment: for wont work in my case ,I have tried that before

Comment: well it has worked with @jeroen method ..
am gettting expected result now.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem.  The reason that child elements are possible in an array structure is so that you don't have to manually suffix keys that belong to the same "group".  Just make the first level key `slugs` then keep pushing children into its subarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get what is in the session in an array and then append it back to the session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['slug'])){
    $_SESSION['slug'] = array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['slug'], $_POST['prod_slug']);
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

This would assume that you initialize $_SESSION['slug'] as an array.

Comment: getting blank array
**slug=> **

Comment: @mohammadharis I added a check for empty this should catch issues when you do not have any data yet

Comment: i have data but the session is not getting it

Comment: @mohammadharis One more update checking the session rather then a variable. I tested this and it appears to be working. If you get errors please post them.

Comment: well I have got the answer but your work is also appreciable .
your code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

for community use:

```
<?php

session_start();

 $slug = $_POST['prod_slug'];
$_SESSION['slugs'][] = $slug;
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION);
print_r($_SESSION);
return false;

?>
```