# Not sure how to write this IF statement?

Tags: php

I'm not sure how to write this. I have a variable called `$group` the value could be `a`,`b` or `c`. I also have variables called `$a`, `$b` and `$c`. How do I write something that states if `$group=a` then use `$a`, if `$group=b` then use `$b` and if `$group=c` then use `$c`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable names in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Comment: I have updated answer below. have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this ??

```
$a = "a"; // $a is variable and "a" is its value and its a string.

$b = "b";

$c = "c";


if ($group == "a")  // here a is just string value not variable. 
{
    echo $a;
}
elseif ($group == "b")
{
    echo $b;
}
else
{
    echo $c;
}
```

Or

**Variable of variables**

Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names. That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically. A normal variable is set with a statement such as:

```
<?php
$a = 'hello';
?>
```

A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, hello, can be used as the name of a variable by using two dollar signs. i.e.

```
<?php
$$a = 'world';
?>
```

At this point two variables have been defined and stored in the PHP symbol tree: $a with contents "hello" and $hello with contents "world". Therefore, this statement:

```
<?php
echo "$a ${$a}";
?>
```

produces the exact same output as:

```
<?php
echo "$a $hello";
?>
```

i.e. they both produce: **hello world.**

For more info [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

With Rahul's help and a tiny bit of tweaking this was my working end result.

```
if ($group == "a") 
{
    $group=$a;
}
elseif ($group == "b")
{
    $group=$b;
}
else
{
    $group=$c;
}
```