# embedding variables within class variables

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to create a function that can set a variable of id, name and url for 3 categories. I wanted to use one function do them all

```
$this->set_variables('main,con,feat');

function set_variables($cats) {
    $cats = explode(',',$cats);
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        $this->$cat.'_id' = $cat;
        $qry = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT categories_name,categories_url FROM categories WHERE categories_id=$this->$cat.'_id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row);
        $this->$cat.'_name' = $row['categories_name'];
        $this->$cat.'_url' = $row['categories_url'];
    }
}
```

So by the end of it, $this->main_id, $this->main_name, $this->main_url, $this->con_id, $this->con_name, etc... will all be set variables. But I am struggling with finding a way to include the variable, I have tired:

```
$this->$cat.'_id'
$this->[$cat]_id
$this->{$cat}_id
```

And various other attempts, but dont seem to be able to get any of them to set.
So how do I set these variables?

Comment: Besides that you probably want to use arrays for this, you didn't tried out: `$this->{$cat . "_id"}` yet. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9257505/3933332)

Comment: sorry missed this line of code $cats = implode(',',$cats);

Comment: why did you use `implode`? you must use `explode`.  then try this instread `$this->"{$cat}_id" = $cat;`

Comment: oops, I meant explode!

Comment: why u use `$this->$cat.'_id'`, this can only call when public $main_id is exist on your class.just use $cat is more better..