# Variable in a variable

Tags: php, variables

This is the first time I've come across this issue. How can I get a variable where the variable determines the variable to get.

```
$foobar_list = '123123';
$type = 'foobar'
echo {$type}_list;
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. It is impossible to search for something you don't know the name of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

As stated there, you need to access it as `echo ${$type . '_list'}`

Edit: fixed a typo