# Not getting dynamic variable names PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to print the values of variable but it prints 12 only

```
$str1="abhishek";
$str2="ashish";
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
{
echo $str.$i;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Comment: You're concatenating `$str` with `$i`. You really are only echoing `$i` (`1`, then `2`) and you should be getting undefined variable `$str` notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$str1="abhishek";
$str2="ashish";
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    echo ${"str".$i};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a better practice:

```
<?php 
$str = array("abhishek","ashish");

for($i=0; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
echo $str[$i].'<br>';
}
?>
```