# Variable & post method issue in for loop

Tags: for-loop

According to the value of count variable `($count = 3)`, I need to get output like this.

```
$color_1 = $_POST["color-1"];
$color_2 = $_POST["color-2"];
$color_3 = $_POST["color-3"];
```

I tried this method but it did not work.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $color_.$i = $_POST["color-.$i"];
}
```

Thanks so much for your helps & interestings.

Comment: Do you want to compose a variable dynamically? What kind of object is $color_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for ($i = 1, $count = count($_POST); $i <= $count; $i++) {
    ${"color_{$i}"} = $_POST["color-{$i}"];
}

echo $color_1;
echo $color_2;
```

Comment: But, there is such a problem. When i add another input to the form, I get this error. Notice: Undefined index: prod-color-3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\index.php on line 66

Comment: If the other input not has a name like `prod-color-*` the for loop is failure because I count all values of POST `$count = count($_POST)`, change `$count` to the number of inputs with name like `prod-color-*`

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your name and variable via curly brackets. If not you just try to use the value of your variable $i.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {    
    ${"color_" . $i} = ${_POST["'color-" . $i . "'"]};
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php) example out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got an error when I tested the code with the following variables ($color_1, $color_2). Output: http://i.cubeupload.com/gtzjje.png