# Use a PHP variable as part of another variable name

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable called $repeater, which will either be low, moderate or high.

I also have variables called...

```
$low_protein_feed
$moderate_protein_feed
$high_protein_feed
```

I want to call one of these variables depending on what the value of $repeater is.

I got as far as this...

```
echo "${$repeater}_protein_feed";
```

...which outputs moderate_protein_feed, for example. But it echoes as text, when I want it to be echoing the value of $moderate_protein_feed variable.

I feel like I'm not far off. 
Thanks for any input

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php but dont, use an array instead

Comment: `$protein_feed=array('low'=>'1','moderate'=>'2','high'=>'3');` `echo $protein_feed[$repeater];`

Comment: Yes, as smith suggests, use an array then use a switch.

Answer (score 2):

Though i advise against this sort of programming, Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names. That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically. A normal variable is set with a statement such as:
you will want to use $$ to set the variable to a variable name. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Test scenario:

```
$myvariable = "hello";
$$myvariable = "hello2";
```

is the same as

```
$hello = "hello2";
```

---

for your case:

```
$low_protein_feed = "test1";
$moderate_protein_feed = "test2";
$high_protein_feed = "test3";

$repeater = "low";
echo ${$repeater . "_protein_feed"};
```

returns test1

check out a related security article http://rgaucher.info/php-variable-variables-oh-my.html

Answer (score 2):

let me purpose an alternative approach, one that most developers agree is better than using variable variables:

```
//array for the protein_feed's
    $protein_feed=array('low'=>'1','moderate'=>'2','high'=>'3'); 
//then to select one based on the value of $repeater
    echo $protein_feed[$repeater];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to do something like this:

```
<?php

// Example - though you should use objects, key -> values, 
// arrays instead in my opinion.

$low_protein_feed = "Low protein";
$moderate_protein_feed = "Lots of protein";
$high_protein_feed = "high grade protein";

$types = array("low", "moderate", "high");

foreach($types as $type) {

    echo ${$type . '_protein_feed'} . " \n";

}
```

Output:

```
$ php testme.php 
Low protein 
Lots of protein 
high grade protein
```

However, you should really use something like this:

```
$types = array("low", "moderate", "high");
$proteins=array('low'=>'1','moderate'=>'2','high'=>'3'); 

foreach($types as $type) {
    echo $proteins[$type];
}
```

More advanced design, you can use objects and declare a type of said object and use a standard type for projects.

Further reading on dynamic variable names here and the differences between PHP5/7 :

[Using braces with dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

http://www.dummies.com/programming/php/how-to-use-php-variable-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Another way: $GLOBALS[$side . $zi_char]