# name and value of php variables as column values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named `what` with values like this:
`earth` `sun` `sea` `sky` ...

I need to create php variables named as this values and give to that variables  the same values.

for example:

```
$earth = 'earth';
$sun = 'sun';
...
```

I tried:

```
$st = $db->prepare("select what from bdef");
$st->execute();
while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
    ${$row['what']} = $row['what'];
}

echo $earth;
```

Result: `Unknown variable...`

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do you need to dynamically create variables with such specific names? It is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php), but as several people mention in the comments there: why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: @Loek, because I have over 20 values and need 20 variables, and trying to make the code shorter.

Comment: Would it not be better to put them in an array

Comment: Maybe you could retrieve the database records as an array and use that?

Comment: @puerto if all you need is to echo the variable, you might as well `while ($row = $st->fetch()) { echo $row['what']; }` or as the other suggested, save everything into an array and use that later on.

Comment: And this code should work (tested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) In my example code I used a function, just to keep it all contained within the scope of the function without stray global variables in your namespace.

```
function dostuff($row) {
  extract($row);
  echo $earth;
}
$st = $db->prepare("select what from bdef");
$st->execute();
while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
    dostuff($row);
}
```