# Reference assignment with a ternary operator

Tags: php

I've commented the code for easier readibility.

```
function logRequest($cached = false) {

    // This function logs the number of two types of events: (1) cached and (2) uncached/upstream request

    // References to frequently addressed array keys, for brevity
    $lc = &$_SESSION['loads']['cache'];
    $lu = &$_SESSION['loads']['upstream'];

    // Add to one session variable or the other, depending on the type of event
    $s = ($cached ? &$lc : &$lu);
    $s = (isset($s) ? $s : 0) + 1; 

    // Begin dumping the counts to a file, but only every 25 calls for each client
    if(($lc ?? 0) + ($lu ?? 0) < 25) return;
    $logArray = (file_exists($logFile = '../runtime/requests.json') ? json_decode(file_get_contents($logFile),true) : []); 

    // Define array structure for dumping to a file
    $today = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');
    $ac = &$logArray[$today]['cache access'];
    $au = &$logArray[$today]['upstream request'];

    // Do incrementing
    $ac = (isset($ac) ? $ac : 0) + $lc;
    $au = (isset($au) ? $au : 0) + $lu;

    // Reset counters in the session
    $lc = $lu = 0;

    // Finally, save to file
    file_put_contents($logFile, json_encode($logArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

The line I am talking about is this:

```
$s = ($cached ? &$lc : &$lu);
```

And the error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in...

How do I go about assigning a reference in this case? Surely there must be a way to use the ternary operator, right?

P.S. I am a very casual programmer so I would be grateful if you could point out any other bad practices in my code.

Comment: Why are you using ampersands to begin with is what I'd like to know.

Comment: It'd be nice to know on which line that's happening. But I'm pretty sure it starts before that line of code you say the error's on.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am working with references. The very next line modifies the referenced variable; The line I've quoted is indeed the one that's causing the error. If I rewrite it to if/else, everything works well. In fact, "$s = &${$cached ? 'lc': 'lu'};" works just as well. I'm just not entirely sure it's a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$cached ? $s = &$lc : $s = &$lu;
```

---

Add some explanation about the code. Sorry for my bad english, I am ashamed to express in English.

> If the value of the first subexpression is TRUE (non-zero), then the second subexpression is evaluated, and that is the result of the conditional expression. Otherwise, the third subexpression is evaluated, and that is the value.

this is from [php expressions manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php#language.expressions).

the reason of we can't use `$s = $cached ? &$lc : &$lu;` is ternary operator need a expression but `&$lc` and `&$lu` not a expression.

we can test this code

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$a;
```

It's no error.

but this

```
<?php
$a = 5;
&$a;
```

throw an error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting end of file in /usercode/file.php on line 3

The above is my opinion, I hope you can understand.

It's too difficult to using english for me.(ㄒoㄒ)

Comment: Can you give some explanation about that?

Comment: Thanks, Zane. What a clever solution, that's probably not what the ternary operator was made for. But it works.

@NicoHaase, depending on whether $cached evaluates to true or false, either $=&$lc, or $s=&$lu will be evaluated next. But in order to evaluate assignment operators, php will do the assignment. To the variable $s in the function scope, in this case.

In other words, the ternary operator syntax is:
condition ? do_if_condition_evaluates_to_true : do_if_evaluates_to_false;

Comment: There should be some explanation added to the answer itself such that people can learn from it - it's not about me not knowing what that code does

Answer (score 0):

A working alternative would be employing dynamic variable names:

```
$s = &${$cached ? 'lc': 'lu'};
```

Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772533/9986646