# php combine parameter to new variable

Tags: php

I make a php file it named as baca.php
like this :

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$admin$id="anything";
?>
```

I want to make new variable with ID parameter value
like
ex: 
if ID parameter value is 1 so the variable is
$admin1="";
if ID parameter value is 2 so the variable is
$admin2="";

Help me please ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using braces with dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Comment: `${"admin$id"}="anything";`

Answer (score 0):

this is for limited variable:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
if($id==='1'){
$admin1="anything";
}elseif($id==='2'){
$admin2="anything";
}//you can add more here
?>
```

i recommend:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id']-1;
$admins=array('admin1','admin2','admin3');//edit this array to add more
$the_admin=$admins[$id];//now this your admin with single variable
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$admin1="hello";
$admin2="world";
$id=$_GET['id'];
$adminx='$admin'.$id;?>

if id=1 i will get $admin1
i want to exec the output ($admin1)

Comment: by my knowledge, this is not possible and use the recommended method, this best for you or wait for another ans.thanks

Comment: @MahfuzarRahman I suggest you read the linked duplicate answer so you can see how it should be done.