# PHP - Find alias from given array and convert found respected values to individual seperate array

Tags: php, arrays

For example:
I have sample array with dynamic values.

```
$sample = array('a.col1','a.col2','b.col1','c.col1','c.col2','d.col5',......);
```

where a,b,c,d are table alias.

How can I separate each table columns into separate individual arrays, how can I get below output ?

```
$a = array('col1','col2');
$b = array('col1');
$c = array('col1','col2');
$d = array('col5');
```

Update : no need of alias name in array values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to promote [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9257505/2943403), but it does satisfy your requirement of individualized variables in a very concise way.

`strstr()` with a 3rd parameter of `true` will isolate the table alias which is then used as the array variable's name.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QLh9b))

```
$sample = array('a.col1','a.col2','b.col1','c.col1','c.col2','d.col5');

foreach ($sample as $column) {
    ${strstr($column, '.', true)}[] = $column;
}

var_export($a);
var_export($b);
var_export($c);
var_export($d);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a.col1',
  1 => 'a.col2',
)array (
  0 => 'b.col1',
)array (
  0 => 'c.col1',
  1 => 'c.col2',
)array (
  0 => 'd.col5',
)
```

---

After question update...

You can split your strings into two halves using the dot as the delimiter.  I can't imagine more than one dot in the strings, but I use the 3rd parameter of `explode()` to improve clarity and allow the function to finish quickly.

Rather than calling `list()` to declare variables for the exploded values, I am using square brace syntax to spare iterated function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8Cjb8))

```
foreach ($sample as $column) {
    [$alias, $column] = explode('.', $column, 2);
    $$alias[] = $column;
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'col1',
  1 => 'col2',
)array (
  0 => 'col1',
)array (
  0 => 'col1',
  1 => 'col2',
)array (
  0 => 'col5',
)
```

Comment: How if alias is dynamic for exmaple "cde." instead of only "c." ?

Comment: That will make no difference to my solution.  You can test my solutions by changing the input values in my demo links.  The other speed posted answers do not meet your clear requirements.

Comment: Normally I refuse to answer questions that fail to include a coding attempt, but because other volunteers have provided inadequate solutions, I had to adjust my principles so that you received a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_walk` with `explode`

```
array_walk($sample, function($v) use (&$r){
   $arr      = explode('.', $v);
   $alias    = isset($arr[0]) ? $arr[0] : '';
   $r[$alias][] = isset($arr[1]) ? $arr[1] : '';
});
```

After that you can use `EXTRACT` to separate them in individual array

```
 extract($r);//// You will have $a, $b, $c ,$d with each alias
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/HSHcK

Comment: OP says: "_How can i seperate each table colummns into seperate individual arrays?_"  Please see the expected result in the question.

Comment: Fyi, `isset($arr[0])` will never evaluate false.

Answer (score 1):

Create a key with the first 2 characters of the string. Keep putting in an array and finally print the array.

if the alias is a combination of letters, either explode with `.` and use the first part as key. (as in implementation)

```
$sample = array('a.col1','a.col2','b.col1','c.col1','c.col2','d.col5');
$newArray=array();
foreach( $sample as $value){
  $key =  (explode(".",$value))[0];  // get the first part before dot.
  $newArray[$key."."][] =$value;  // not I am appending a dot
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a.] => Array
        (
            [0] => a.col1
            [1] => a.col2
        )

    [b.] => Array
        (
            [0] => b.col1
        )

    [c.] => Array
        (
            [0] => c.col1
            [1] => c.col2
        )

    [d.] => Array
        (
            [0] => d.col5
        )

)
```

Comment: How if alias is "cde" instead of only "c" ?

Comment: OP says: "_How can i seperate each table colummns into seperate individual arrays?_"  Please see the expected result in the question.

Comment: @Rahul_Dange that's just an idea, string can be broken based on `.` using strpos

Comment: @mickmackusa each item of the array shows the required array right?  he can further use {} to dynamically generate varibales, like `$array{$i}` if he needs the values in exact variables.. no?

Comment: The point is, it is your responsibility to deliver the expected result -- if you are going to post an answer.  Of course, I know how to do this bit, but we are here to educate the OP and future researchers who do not know how to do these things.

Comment: true, I actually try to give some hints so that OP may start getting the idea and use his own tricks to solve the issue. We know that storing array in variables won't be that useful when you have a complete dataset ready

Answer (score 0):

The other way:

```php
$sample = array('a.col1','a.col2','b.col1','c.col1','c.col2','d.col5');
$new = [];
foreach($sample as $value){
    $arr = explode(".", $value);
    if(array_key_exists($arr[0],$new)){
        array_push($new[$arr[0]], $arr[1]);
    }else{;
        $new[$arr[0]][] = $arr[1];
    }
}
```

Output:
https://3v4l.org/eYKDc

Comment: OP says: "_How can i seperate each table colummns into seperate individual arrays?_" Please see the expected result in the question.

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.