# Anonymous function with variable in function name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to do something pretty out there with a PHP function.

I want to call a function but based on the area of the site, I want it to call a different function. This occurs in WP theme activation, but each theme that calls the function has different unique extras. Alas, I digress:

```php
$mb_theme_action_mbinout = function() {
    // this is code is for testing
    $mb_locations = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
        $mb_locations[] =   array(
                                'a' => 'Test item ' . $i,
                                'b' => 'loc0' . $i,
                                'c' => 'group1'
                            );
    }

    var_dump( $mb_locations );

};

$theme = function() {
    echo 'mb_theme_action_' . get_option('stylesheet'); // output: mb_theme_action_mbinout
};

$theme();
```

The above doesn't work, but I have also tried:

```php
$theme = 'mb_theme_action_' . get_option('stylesheet');
$theme();

// also

$$theme();
```

I know this is not conventional, but was wondering if there was a way for it to work? It would only be called once.

Comment: Probably related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php

Comment: wow - thank you @JulienGabriel. I can either accept your answer or answer my own with the code?

Comment: You can do both. But an upvote is always welcome!