# change variable name in a foreach

Tags: php

How can I change the `$rank` variable name to `$rank1`, `$rank2` and so on depending on the user `$userID`?

```
foreach($myClient as $users){
   $username = $users->usrnm;
   $userID = $users->usrID;
   $rank...
   
}
```

Comment: Using numbered variables is usually a good sign that using an array is a better solution.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and what's in `$myClient`?

Comment: Dynamic variable naming is bad. Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: Also see the first comment below the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php

Comment: @nice_dev Can you explain to me why dynamic variables is a bad thing?

Comment: @Marcel Ok, if you create dynamic variables, can you assure $rank465 exists always, to use it in your code? There are other reasons too though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do it like this:

```
foreach($myClient as $users){
   $username = $users->usrnm;
   $userID = $users->usrID;
   ${'rank'.$userID} = 'something';
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$userId1 = 1;
$userId2 = 2;

$rankVarName1 = sprintf('rank%s', $userId1);
$rankVarName2 = sprintf('rank%s', $userId2);

$$rankVarName1 = 'rank var value';
$$rankVarName2 = 'other rank';

var_dump($rank1); // rank var value
var_dump($rank2); // other rank
```

but I recommend you use an array

```
$ranks = [];

$userId1 = 1;
$userId2 = 2;

$ranks[$userId1] = 'rank var value';
$ranks[$userId2] = 'other rank';

var_dump($ranks[$userId1]); // rank var value
var_dump($ranks[$userId2]); // other rank
```