# from php 5.4 to php 7 , useing dynamic variables is confused

Tags: php, dynamic

my php is update from php 5.4 to php 7.0.33 , but php code get an error with Dynamic variables

php 5.4 some code like this...

```
$attributes=array('boy','girl','none' );
$this->boy = 'eric';
$this->girl = 'lili';
$this->none = 'who';
            
echo $attributes[0];                    //=>php 5 is "boy"  | php 7 is "boy"
print_r( $this->$attributes[0] );       //=>php 5 is "eric" | php 7 is empty
print_r( $this->${attributes}[0] );     //=>php 5 is "eric" | php 7 is empty
```

when I use in php 7 shome code get epmty, how can I do to resolve this problem

I already watching the refer page [Using braces with dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php/35772533#35772533) , but still confused

Comment: How about `$this->{$attributes[0]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamic variables like this, you need to wrap the string in curly braces.  You almost had it there in your last line.  However, remember that it's not the array `$attributes` that you're using to indicate the dynamic variable, it's the string at `$attributes[0]`.

So this should work:

```php
$this->{$attributes[0]}
```

Dynamic variables names are powerful, but easy to get confused with.  If you have the option, I'd recommend using just an array:

```php
$this->attributes = [
    "boy"  => "eric",
    "girl" => "lili",
    "none" => "who"
];

echo $this->attributes["boy"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are searching for is

```php
 print_r( $this->{$attributes[0]} );
```